# Extract substring from path. Make sure the extracted substring isn't followed by a character

Tags: regex, string, path, applescript

Let's say I have this string:

```
/folder1/folder2/match/folder3/match.app
```

I want to extract a substring that **ends with** a matching condition ("`match`") but that **isn't followed** by a specific character ("`.`")

*The result should be:*

```
/folder1/folder2/match
```

---

### Case 1

In the case of "`match.`" before "`match`" followed by any other character or none:

```
/folder1/folder2/match.app/folder3/match/folder4
```

*The result should be:*

```
/folder1/folder2/match.app/folder3/match
```

Since the first "`match`" is followed by a "`.`"

---

### Case 2

In case there are two matches:

```
/folder1/folder2/match/folder3/match/folder4
```

*The result should be:*

```
 /folder1/folder2/match
```

I want to keep just the first substring.

---

### Case 3

In the case there isn't any "`match`" without a following "`.`":

```
/folder1/folder2/match.app
```

*The result should be:*

```
False
```

The regex should output "`False`" when there is no occurrences.

---

### Case 4

In case there is a "`match`" followed by any other character besides "`/`" or "nothing more" :

```
/folder1/folder2/matcha/match/folder3
```

or

```
/folder1/folder2/matcha/match
```

*The result should be:*

```
 /folder1/folder2/matcha/match
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

**NOTE:** I want to use this regex in Applescript:

```
set strRegEx to ???
set strResult to find text strRegEx in strTextToSearch with regexp and string result
```

**UPDATE:** Added Case 4

Comment: where you want to ad code is there any javascript or .htaccess or any language file?

Comment: In applescript: set strResult to find text strRegEx in strTextToSearch with regexp and string result

Comment: `/(?<=\/match)(?!\.)(.*)/` should do it in php PCRE. I am not sure what engine is used in applescript.

Comment: How can I get "False" when there isn't a match?

Comment: The bellow answers they all are good interpreted by applescript (except the "escaping" char is "\\" and not just "\")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
.*?match(?!\.)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdvaYQ/1) (Note: The `^` in this demo is only added to show multiple examples together; you shouldn't need it.)

Explanation:

> `.` - matches any character
>
> `*?` - repeats the previous pattern as many times as necessary, but at little as possible ("non-greedy").
>
> `match` - literal text for the word "match"
>
> `(?!...)` a negative lookahead; the contained pattern is not included in the result, and **cannot** be matched.
>
> `\.` a literal "." (the \ prevents it from being treated as "any character", like above)

---

**Edit:**

Taking into consideration the "case 4" that you've now added, you could perhaps change the regex to:

```
.*?match(?=\/|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdvaYQ/2)

Explanation:

> `(?=...)` is a *positive* lookahead.
>
> `\/` matches a literal "/" character.
>
> `$` matches the end of the line.
>
> `\/|$` matches *either* of the above.

Comment: Almost perfect! I forgot a condition. Updated my question. Also, can I get a custom output ("False") whenever there isn't any findings?

Comment: I have updated my answer for "case 4". I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve with this  `"False"` variable; I'd need to know a little more context in how you're using it... I've also never used applescript before, so someone else may have a better idea than me :)

Comment: Now it's really perfect! About the "False".. I thought I could output a custom text if a condition was or wasn't matched without if..else in my applescript code :)

Comment: What does `strResult` currently equal in your code, when this happens? `NULL`, or similar? (As I say, I don't know applescript...) - Could you not just do something like `if strResult == NULL ....` already?

Comment: That's exactly what I'll do. Well, many thanks for everything! You got it!

Answer (score 1):

For most of cases the first match in the line with Regex `(^.*?match(?!\.))` regex would be enough.

Check it out on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yl4kmh/2)

- `/folder1/folder2/match/folder3/match.app` matches `/folder1/folder2/match`
- `/folder1/folder2/match.app/folder3/match/folder4` matches `/folder1/folder2/match.app/folder3/match`
- `/folder1/folder2/match/folder3/match/folder4` matches both:

  - `/folder1/folder2/match`
  - `/folder3/match`
- `/folder1/folder2/match.app` doesn't match anything.

Would you consider using rather of a specific Regex to each case?

Edit. If you use the `gm` options and add the `^` to the beggining of the Regex, you could get the correct part of the String as the only match.

Answer (score 0):

I think u are looking for something like this.

```
.*?match[^\.]
```

> breakdown 
>   `.` all characters
> `*?` 0 till endless times but not greedy
>  `match`the word match
> `[^` not followed by the following list
>  `\.` a dot (the \ is to escape it for being read as a dot and not as all characters.
>  `]` end of the list

if u read only the first found match u get for your case 2 only the first match. if u read all matches u get also the `folder3/match` as a result

and in case 3 u get no match found

Comment: This seems to be almost there. However I receive an extra "/" at the end of the substring. Also, can I force it to just give me the first occurrence (in case 2). And can I get a custom output ("False") whenever there isn't any findings?

Comment: if its always at the first of the line u can use this `^.*?match(?!\.)` the ^in front makes shure its at the start of the line. to not have the dot u need the negative lookahead . [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xSjoCO/1)